# Compare two arrays and if have same value assign them into variable

Tags: php, arrays

I wonder how to do this. I have two arrays, I need to assign them into a variable. The example below shows the output. When I print out the output using `print_r()`, the value that I want to match is "**id_car**"..

1) variable used for this array is $data.

```
Array ( [0] => 26 )
```

2) variable used for this array is $dataKereta.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 25 [id_car] => 25 [1] => 23 [id_user] => 23 ) 

[1] => Array ( [0] => 26 [id_car] => 26 [1] => 23 [id_user] => 24)

[2] => Array ( [0] => 27 [id_car] => 27 [1] => 23 [id_user] => 25  ) )
```

what i want is, find the same value in 1st array with 2nd array,if same assign them into variable..

I tried do like this

```
foreach ($dataKereta as $dk => $dk1) {
    if($data[$dk] != $dk1['id_car']) {
        $not_same[] = $dk1;
    }
    else {
        $same[] = $dk1;
    }
}
```

The code I made above has find the match value, if not match assign into the $not_same variable and otherwise.. this code is OK when have the value for 1st variable like this :

```
Array ( [0] => 25 [1] => 26 )
```

but if i remove the "[0] => 25" value,it start not detect the 26.. i'm sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this if your data has multiple elements**

ie, $data = (0=>'26',1=>'27');

```
foreach ($data as $dataval) {
    foreach ($dataKereta as $key=>$dk) {
        if ($dataval == $dk['id_car']) {
            $same[] = $dk['id_car'];
        } 
    }
}

foreach ($dataKereta as $key=>$dk) {
    if (!in_array($dk['id_car'],$same)) {
        $not_same[] = $dk['id_car'];
    }
}
```

**Result**

same:
Array ( [0] => 26 [1] => 27 )
not_same:
Array ( [0] => 25 )

Comment: This code does not working for me. there is no ouput return for variable $in, and both of my array having same value. And i want to search it using by spesifiec condition "id_car". this problem really stuck me.

Comment: I'll try to update it using your variables.  Can you show exactly what you want the output to look like?

Comment: try to remove "'21','22','23','24','25'" in $data variable and just left $data1 = array('26');. And see the output you got.

Comment: For more accurate, i need the NOT SAME value. The "25,27" should be in $not_same variable, and the "26" assign into $same variable. Do you get it??

Comment: I updated it again, hopefully one of the two solutions will make sense for your purposes.

Comment: seen it worked!. But the other problem appear. Try add the 1st variable of array to be like this $data = array(0=>'25',1=>'26'); and see the output. The 26 value not listed in $same variable. This happens because the the condition is using $data[0]. It just search for index 0. If change to increament, your code to be same like mine in the question.

Comment: Voilllaa.. thank you. at last,it works correctly.. Thank u so much @DrewP84

Comment: yea, sorry, i realized the first code snippet was the same as yours after i posted it.  glad the second one worked :)